# magento image crop on upload

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In my Magento project, I customised the blog extension and added an image uploader for each post. The image field is using "image" as the field type. In the controller, I am instantiating the uploader with `Varien_File_Uploader_Image` class which inherits `Varien_File_Uploader`. But obviously the code is wrong in these two files, the constructor of `Varien_File_Uploader_Image` is wrong and crop() method isn't working as well. I wonder is there an existing functionality I could utilise in Magento to do the cropping? I know for product images, there's functionality for generating the thumbnails but I don't know where that piece of code is.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `Varien_Image` class to add crop functionality in your custom module

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .'your_folder'. DS;
imname = 'yourimagename.jpg';

$img_location = $path.$imbfname;
$image= new Varien_Image($img_location);
$image->crop($top, $left, $right, $bottom)
$image->save($img_location);
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is this crop() method doesn't automatically calculate the aspect ratio of the uploaded image, it just requires specific pixels you want cut off from each side.

Comment: you can use function keepAspectRatio from same class if you want to see how to use just see in core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Image.php. hope this will sure help you. pls dnt forget to acpt my answer and vote up pls

Comment: I end up using resize() for my purpose. Thanks!